# How to get the value of the childnodes using getElementsById

Tags: javascript, html

evening... I want to know which node or value is selected from the drop down menu ( select tag) when I click apply... i dont seem to refer to them correctly.. please help!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function apply(){
var xy = document.getElementById("hmm").childNodes;
var ab = xy.value;
alert(ab);
}
</script>
</head>


<body>
<div id="unique">
<select id="hmm" name="drop">
<option value="" id="text area">Text Area</option>
<option value="" id="paragraph">Paragraph</option>
<option value="" id="radio">Radio Button</option>
<option value="" id="delete">Delete</option>
</select>
<button id="apply" onclick="apply()">Apply</button> 
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the selected value of dropdownlist using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript)

Comment: That was helpful as well @zzzzBov
Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function apply() {
    var selectBox = document.getElementById("hmm");
    var selectedOption = selectBox.options[selectBox.options.selectedIndex];
    alert(selectedOption.value);
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AN3X5/1/)

Comment: thanks... but the alert is no longer poping up to tell me which node is selected

Comment: Please check it now... add look at the accompanying jsfiddle

Comment: Note, you don't actually have any "values" assigned to any of your options.

Comment: Exactly!     @El Guapo
Thanks a lot... its kickin now :D